# Symfony3 not logged in after passing the login form

Tags: php, security, authentication, symfony

I am new to Symfony and stucking at the security part.
I've read the documentation about the user security:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

I've read the documentation about how to create a login form:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

So, when i log in with httpbasic everything is working fine (except logging out obviously).

If I use my form login, it let me pass when I use correctly credentials. But after logging in successfully I am still Anonymous..

My security.yaml:

```
security:
encoders:
    Bundle\Entity\Users:
        algorithm: bcrypt
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
providers:
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: Bundle:Users
            property: email
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                admin:
                    password: admin
                    roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
                user1:
                    password: user
                    roles: 'ROLE_USER'
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    default:
        pattern: ^/backend
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
           login_path:   login
           check_path:   check
           default_target_path: /backend
        provider: our_db_provider
        logout:
           path: logout
           target: /
           success_handler: ~
           invalidate_session: true

    main:
        anonymous: ~

access_control:
   - { path: ^/backend/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
   - { path: ^/backend/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

View is the same code like in the symfony documentation:

```
        <form action="{{ path('check') }}" class="form-signin form-group" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" class="form-control"/>

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" class="form-control"/>

        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Why I'm not logged in correctly after my login?

Can someone help me or give me an hint how to solve it?

Thanks in advice
Michael

EDIT:
I just solved my issue after posting this question...!

The only problem was my default set session handler_id in my config.yaml.
to solve this, change in config.yaml:

```
framework:
    session:
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
```

to:

```
session:
    handler_id: ~
```

Comment: Hey Michael, your question/ answer worked for me too! Do you know what's the problem with the standard config?

Comment: And why it obviously doesn't start a new session?

Comment: @kinske Hello kinske, great that it could help you! I am sorry, I could not find out why the standard config is not working... 
If someone knows why, it would be great if he could answer this question.

Comment: Yeah that's really strange, it didn't throw or log any error...

Comment: True, I didn't find any explanation for this. I was lucky with finding this solution and I'm happy that it's just working fine.